# download images in iOS app and show these images in collectionView cells

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, uicollectionview

I am using this method to download the image:

```
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/Url-logo.png"]]];

// save file.
//NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

//NSLog(@"%@", documentDir);
NSLog(@"Saving Image");

NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Url-logo.png",documentDir];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES]; */

NSLog(@"image Saved");
```

now i want to download multiple images and save then in an array… then show them in CollectionView cells using indexPaths of array…

is this right way to do it or not…
if yes then what should i do to save multiple images in array and show them in collection view
any idea / help …………..

Comment: Hi Zaibi, perhaps you are new to StackOverflow but a lot of us put a lot of effort into answering users questions. Answering questions benefits both parties and its a great learning experience for everyone. You currently have 2 answers to your question and you have not replied to them in the comments. Please either up vote a question or enter the debate in the comments but don't leave this question unattended.

Comment: @DanielG sorry for late reply… actually i was not there for some last hours.. and the good news is this i have solved my issue… thanks for your cooperation and support

Comment: No worries Zaibi, If you have managed to solve the issue please provide your answer or vote up the answer that helped you, that way anyone else coming in here with the same question can learn something:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the -[UIImage initWithData:] method will only work if the image data is already on the file system. What you DON'T want to do is download a bunch of images and save them in an array. The reason for this is that you don't want all these images residing in memory (especially the ones that are not visible).

Whilst there are libraries that will help you I would encourage attempting this strategy yourself as it seems to me that you are not yet familiar with iOS.

Based on my understanding of your question you are going to need to address the following concepts

1. Image Disk Storage Strategy
2. Image File Path Retrieval
3. Networking
4. Collection View Integration

**Image Disk Storage Strategy**

Assuming you want to save these images to disk and use them on the next App start-up, then you are going to want to read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html for an idea of where these images should be stored on disk. For instance, use the TMP directory for resources that the App can easily fetch again and you don't want them backed up.

**Image File Path Retrieval**

Since you are populating your collection view using some form of data source, this data source should also be responsible for returning the file path for an image at a given index path. This way when your collection view queries its data source for a cell at a particular index path you will fetch all the relevant information for said cell and configure your cell appropriately. In your situation this data source will simply provide the local and remote file paths for a given image at a particular index.

The number of items in your collection view should affect which strategy you use to design your data source. If there is only a few file paths (< 10) then you could just use an NSDictionary where the key is the indexPath and the object is your filePath. If you have a lot of images you would definitely need a persistence framework to avoid putting all the image paths into one object residing in memory. One solution would be to persist the file paths to your images in core data, that way you can use a fetched results controller in coordination with your collection view. This would mean fetching for each indexPath the filePath to the image and then setting it on your collectionViewCell. Core Data provides a really great object persistence framework that should get you up and running in no time.

**Networking**

Another issue you are going to need to tackle is managing downloads as the user scrolls. For instance, on a slow connection if you are downloading in a FIFO queue then if the user scrolls to the end of your collection view the images added first will hold up the queue and you won't see the images at the end until every other image is downloaded. One solution is to cancel the requests for cells that are no longer visible. http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/12/16/uitableviewcell-subclasses-and-async-loading is one such article using GCD to render cells asynchronously.

There are a lot of different ways one can approach networking so it ultimately depends on what you need. Some prefer sub-classing UIImageView to provide the functionality for a UIImageView that will automatically download an image from a given URL. You could instantiate this class by providing a remote URL and a local file path URL and the custom subclass would then trigger a download if nothing exists at the local path. Should you implement this strategy you are going to want to add the ability to cancel the download for this custom subclass.

**Collection View Integration**

Your collection view will be responsible for integrating all the above components together. This would mean fetching the number of images to display, populating the collection view with these images, facilitating the usage of the network and canceling image requests for images that are not visible.

The important thing you want to tackle is making solid use of concurrent API. Your networking calls should not block the main thread. I would recommend creating an NSOperationQueue that manages all downloads. This way when you close the collection view you can cancel all the operations on that queue:)

Comment: thanks for the detailed description… let me try this…

Comment: you are saying that, there is no need to download and save images in device / app document directory. but if app has to run off line … then how the images can download and showed in cell…

Comment: You should definitely save them to disk if you want them offline. What I am saying is that you should save them to disk and store the filePaths in a persistence framework. So this way when you save an image you store where you save it somewhere and then when you want to retrieve it you call [UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];

Comment: I updated my answer in the hopes of being more helpful. Please let me know if I'm being confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your way is not good way to do it. Because, every image you download the image, save it in the device, than display it in the `UICollectionViewCell`. It looks like that your images aren't that big, but don't forget device memory is limited. So, you shouldn't really use it like that unless you really need it.

Also, you don't need to save all the images before displaying in the `UICollectionViewCell`, but what you can do is to load your images lazily. There are many third party libraries that you can use to accomplish that, but my recommendation would be [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). You can read more from the documentation and see the examples. You'll see that it's really really simple to use. Most of the process will be transparent to you. You just need to set image url, then it handles everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct way to load images in collection view, Use image lazy loading method to load images in Collection view, Refer this example code for image lazy loading ==> [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)